# I want to write a docker file where my container can load db file from a directory and past it to application directory and on exit wrtie it back

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, devops, docker-volume

I am working with Golang application that saves the information inside sqlite file and that resideds inside the `data/sqlite.db` same directory as docker file. My docker file is something like this

p.s: guys it's my very first docker file please be kind to me :(

```
FROM golang:1.16.4

ENV GIN_MODE=release
ENV PORT=8081

ADD . /go/src/multisig-svc

WORKDIR /go/src/multisig-svc

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o bin/multisig-svc cmd/main.go

EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ./bin/multisig-svc
```

I deployed this application to the Google cloud plateform but somehow the container gets restarted there and after that my db is vanished. So i researched and try to use volumes.
I build the container using this command `docker build -t svc .` and then run it with `docker run -p 8080:8081 -v data:/var/dump -it svc` but i can not see the data folder is getting copied to /var/dump directory. My basic idea is , Whenever the container start it loads the db file from dump and then past it to data directory so application can use it and when it exits it copy it back to dump directory. I don't know if i am on right track any help would really be appreciated.

#Edit
The issue is when no request arrives for 15 minutes GPC shut down the container and start it when there comes a request again. Now the issue is to somehow fetch the db file from dump directory update it and write it back to the dump dir when container goes down for future use.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your application has particularly complex dependencies, and it seems like you don't especially want Docker's filesystem isolation.  Can you build and run this application directly on the host without involving Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze figured out the issue the Google cloud plateform shutdown the container if no request is arriving now this issue is i need to find a mechanism where i can fetch the database from dump update it and save it back to dump on every container start and close .

Comment: Especially if this is in a cloud environment, an embedded database like SQLite might not be the best match.  Can you run a more traditional relational database like PostgreSQL in a separate container, or use a GCP Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Yes i am thinking about it as well.

Comment: may i ask what GCP service you are using? and add it to the details of your question.

Answer (score 3):

For a local run and if you are running on a VM, you need to specify the absolute path of the directory you want to mount as a bind mount into your directory. In this case something like that should work

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8081 -v $(pwd)/data:/var/dump -it svc
```

When you don't specify the absolute path, the volume you're mounting to your running container is a named volume manage by the docker daemon. And it is not located in a path related to your current working directory. You can find more information about how work docker volumes here https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

However there are multiple environment on GCP (app engine, kubernetes, VMs), so depending on your environment you may need to adapt this solution.